# Finding a complex function $f$ and the residue of $f '(z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $U,a$ real positive constants, $\varphi_1, \varphi_2$ $C^1$ functions on $[0,a]$ with $\varphi_1(0) = \varphi_2(0)$ and $\varphi_1(a) = \varphi_2(a)$.

The problem is to find an analytic function $f$ that satisfies:

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}\Im(f'(x+iy))=-U\varphi_2'(x) \quad\mbox{ if }\quad x\in(0,a)\\  
\lim_{y\to 0^-}\Im(f'(x+iy))=-U\varphi_1'(x) \quad\mbox{ if }\quad x\in(0,a)$$

and then compute the residue of $f'(z)$ at $z=0$.

By now, I have made somethings but without get anything. For example, I suppose that $f$ has a power series representation, and I tried to write it in terms of $x+iy$ but the expression was very very difficult, and after all it was not useful.

Then I've tried to write $$f'(z)= \sum_{n=-k}^\infty a_nz^n$$ assuming that $f'$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z=0$, and I dont get anything yet.

And the last idea (a desperate one xD) that I have was:

Integrate the expressions of the limits above  between $0$ and $x\in(0,a)$ to obtain that

$$
\lim_{y\to 0^+}\Im f(x+iy) = \Im f(0) + u\varphi_2(0)- u\varphi_2(x) \quad \mbox{and}\\
\lim_{y\to 0^-}\Im f(x+iy) = \Im f(0) + u\varphi_1(0)- u\varphi_1(x).
$$

but yet, I don't know how I can (if I can) use this.

Any Hint will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematics.SE! In order to help you do your homework (notably different from "to do your homework") it is paramount that you include in your question: 1. Your attempts on the problem; 2. What part of it you're stuck on (see also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803)). If you [edit] your question to provide this information, it is much more likely that we can help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggest. I've made some modifications. :)